# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder' with keras 2.2.4 tensorflow 1.14

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'` when I'm using Keras 2.2.4(since it supports TensorFlow 1.x) 
Tried TensorFlow 1.14 and also 2.0.0, but always same error

Can someone help me resolve this

This is complete log

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-65-dc4f74e64a0b> in <module>
      7 
      8 
----> 9 inputExperiment = Input(shape=(1,),dtype='int8', name='inputExperiment')
     10 x1 = Embedding(output_dim=4,input_dim=50,input_length=1)(inputExperiment)
     11 x1 = Flatten()(x1)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Workspace\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in Input(shape, batch_shape, name, dtype, sparse, tensor)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Workspace\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Workspace\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py in __init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, batch_input_shape, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Workspace\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in placeholder(shape, ndim, dtype, sparse, name)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

Comment: This seems to be a bad installation. Or... (I don't believe this would be the message, but) you are using tensorflow with eager execution (which doesn't accept placeholders).... You should check in your code which version of tensorflow is being used. And I suspect that for tensorflow 2.0 you would need `tf.keras` instead....

Comment: @DanielMöller same code was working fine in kaggle kernel, but I'm seeing this error when I tried in pycharm using anaconda, can u explain me how to not use tensorflow eager execution.?

Comment: What is your tensorflow verion printed by `tf.__version__` in this environment?

Comment: @DanielMöller it says 2.0.0, strange, because I used 1.14 in conda,, can u help me revert this to lower version.?

Comment: You should search the internet on how to create a new "environment" in Anaconda and in this environment you install the versions you need. This is the only save way to install/uninstall things without breaking your previous installations. After you created this environment and installed only the versions you need, then you run your code from this environment. Unfortunately these installation issues are not easy things to tackle.

Comment: So, for tensorflow 2.0.0 you should probably be using `tensorflow.keras` instead of `keras`.

Comment: Keras 2.3 supports TensorFlow 2.0, Keras 2.2.4 does not.

Comment: @DanielMöller thank you, I looked into the environment and created again with different library versions, u can post it as answer so that I can accept the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A placeholder is the initial tensor-like object you use to create a symbolic graph model. (Which is the standard Keras model and old Tensorflow model).

If it can't be found, either your installation is bad or your tensorflow version is 2.0.0 (and thus uses eager mode by default - eager mode doesn't support placeholders).

To use Tensorflow 2.0.0, it's probably better to use `tensorflow.keras` instead of `keras`. (But it may be an idea to test Keras 2.3 as proposed by Matias Valdenegro)

To fix your installation, the safest way is to create a new environment.

You should search the internet on how to create a new "environment" in Anaconda and in this environment you install the versions you need. This is the only safe way to install/uninstall things without breaking your previous installations. After you created this environment and installed only the versions you need, then you run your code from this environment. Unfortunately these installation issues are not easy things to tackle.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.
I had the same problem with 
"from keras.models import load_model"
now it works with "from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model"